# How to back to Main activity from the notification activity?

Tags: java, android

When I press the notification the activity opens, but when I click back the App go to background and still on the same activity.
I wanna go back to `MainActivity` when I click back. what's wrong in my code?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder n;
    String ID = "a" ;
    int id=1 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    public void b2(View view) {

       Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2.class);

       TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
       stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
       stackBuilder.addNextIntent(i);


       PendingIntent pi =  stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

       n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.xx)
            .setContentTitle("don't forget")
            .setContentText("Hello0o0o0o")
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

       notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
       notificationManager.notify(id , n.build());
       id++;
   }



   public void b1(View view) {
       Intent i4 = new Intent(this,Read.class);
       startActivity(i4);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I don't see the problem, but you could override the onBackPressed() function to move back to MainActivity. It's a solution. Also check if you actually are calling this function b2.

Comment: i edit the code that's all my class .  b2 is a function of a button to generate a notifications >>>> do you think where is the problem?

Comment: thank you very much onBackPressed() worked well . but if you know the wrong in my code tell me >>>

Comment: @mazen From what I see, you do not have a onClickListener set up for your buttons. Did you set them up in the xml?